# Forest structure with LaTeX

Tags: tikz-trees, forest

I wanna make a fancier forest structure like this:[image: hierarchical model]

Some advice? I have got a similar structure with TikZ, (but in the opposite way)

Comment: It looks like you've got two separate accounts, which means you cannot edit your original post or leave comments. The Stack Exchange staff can [merge them together for you](//tex.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Moreover, you can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format and add [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: 2nd example of the pgf manual is a great starter, explains each step in full detail. Automatic tree growth can be achieved in tikz with the tree package (chapter 72) or graph drawing functionality (part 4/chapter 72ff). Manual can be found here: http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @Huang_d Doesn't really address doing it in Forest, mind.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Forest? Forest isn't suitable since it is not a tree. @Huang_d's suggestions about the graph drawing facilities are more likely to be helpful. In addition, right now, this is just a do-it-for-me. You say you have code in Ti*k*Z, but apparently want anybody who would help you to start from scratch. That's pointless. It is much easier to work from code than copy from an image. Please edit your question to add a minimal working example which we can copy-paste-compile to work on a solution.

Answer (score 2):

> *Note that I think I ought not answer do-it-for-mes, but sometimes do so anyway. When I do so, I do so for me. If it happens to help somebody, even the questioner, so be it. If not, not. Expect me to be less than sympathetic to requests for fine-tuning, explanation or adjustment.*

Forest isn't suitable. Use the graphs facilities of Ti*k*Z instead. Compile with LuaTeX.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \graph [tree layout, grow'=up, nodes={circle, draw}]
  {
    a <- b <- {c,d <- {f,g},e};
    h <- i <- {j,k <- {l,m} };
  };
  \graph [use existing nodes]
  {
    {f,g} -> j;
    {l,m} -> e;
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: treeish graph]

To do this with Forest, you need a fake root and to add additional edges manually.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow'=90, draw, circle, edge+={<-}},
  [, phantom
    [a[b[c][d[f][g]][e,tikz+={\foreach \i in {!rl121,!rl12l} \draw [<-] (.parent anchor) -- (\i.child anchor);}]]]
    [h[i[j,tikz+={\foreach \i in {!r1121,!r112l} \draw [<-] (.parent anchor) -- (\i.child anchor);}][k[l][m]]]]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: faked forest]